# How XSD refers to XML elements with same name in different namespaces

Tags: xml, reference, xsd, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have this XML Schema that contains a sequence with two refs with the same name, but different namespaces.
`Address` elements are defined in both *Address1.xsd* and *Address2.xsd*

I'm wondering if this is accepted by the standard.

```
 <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn/bpmnCloudProcess/Testnamespace/Process" 
    xmlns:tns7="http://my.namespace.com2" xmlns:tns6="http://my.namespace.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xsd:import namespace="http://my.namespace.com" schemaLocation="Address1.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://my.namespace.com2" schemaLocation="Address2.xsd"/>

        <xsd:element name="start">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="tns6:Address"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="tns7:Address"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

 </xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Yes it's allowed. What made you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, your example is correct** and demonstrates the proper way to reference two `Address` elements distinguished by being in different namespaces.  Just be sure that Address1.xsd has a `targetNamespace` equal to `http://my.namespace.com` and Address2.xsd has a `targetNamespace` equal to `http://my.namespace.com2`.  Here are all three XSDs consistently defined:

## Main XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
     targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn/bpmnCloudProcess/Testnamespace/Process" 
     xmlns:tns7="http://my.namespace.com2"
     xmlns:tns6="http://my.namespace.com"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://my.namespace.com"
              schemaLocation="Address1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://my.namespace.com2"
              schemaLocation="Address2.xsd"/>

  <xsd:element name="start">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="tns6:Address"/>
        <xsd:element ref="tns7:Address"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

### Address1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://my.namespace.com" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="Address"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

### Address2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://my.namespace.com2" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="Address"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you all. @kjhughes